# C++ "toupper" not converting character to uppercase

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char, toupper

I'm trying to convert every letter in a string to uppercase. I'm looping through each character and using `toupper` on it. However, when I print the new string out, it's not working. Sorry if this is a newbie question. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1, str2;
    cin >> str1 >> str2;
    int len = str1.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        toupper(str1[i]);
        toupper(str2[i]);
        cout << str1[i] << " " << str2[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: [`toupper` receives and returns `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) so heed the warning in the **Notes** section of the linked documentation page.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform toupper".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be better, depending on your coding standards:

```
std::transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1.begin(), std::toupper);
std::transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2.begin(), std::toupper);
```

The above uses the STL function `transform` to convert the string to all uppercase.

Answer (score 4):

`std::toupper` returns a value rather than modifying its argument. So you need to do:

```
str1[i] = std::toupper(str1[i]);
str2[i] = std::toupper(str2[i]);
```

in order to actually modify the strings.

If you turn on warnings, e.g with `-Wall` the compiler will tell you that your version of the code has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the modified strings back into the str arrays. Something like this:

```
str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you don't change the elements of the strings because `toupper()` returns a new character, it doesn't change the passed character. You need to make your elements be the same as the returned characters, as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str1[i] = toupper(str1[i]);
    str2[i] = toupper(str2[i]);
    cout << str1[i] << " " << str2[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    toupper(str1[i]);
    toupper(str2[i]);
    cout << str1[i] << " " << str2[i] << endl;
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because the strings `str1` and `str2` in general can have different lengths.

These calls

```
    toupper(str1[i]);
    toupper(str2[i]);
```

has no effect because they change neither `str1[i]` no `str2[i]`.

Also you need to convert the argument of a call of `toupper` to the type `unsigned char`.

You could separately output each string the following way

```
for ( unsigned char c : str1 )
{
    std::cout << ::toupper( c );
}
std::cout << ' ';

for ( unsigned char c : str2 )
{
    std::cout << ::toupper( c );
}
std::cout << '\n';
```